# how to change a::before style by click in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

how to change a::before style by click in jquery?

```js
$("li").click(function () {
 $(this).children('a').css('color','red');
 $(this).children('a::before').css('color','green');
});
```

```css
li > a::before{
 content: "Hello";
padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a>World</a></li>
<li><a>World</a></li>
<li><a>World</a></li>
</ul>
```

each item has ::before in css file i want to change style them by click

Comment: The answer you are looking for might be here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly it's not possible to use pseudo-elements in js
You should use addClass and in your css add .myclass:before

```
$("li").click(function () {
 $(this).children('a').css('color','red');
 $(this).children('a').addClass('customClass');
});

li > a::before{
 content: "Hello";
 padding:5px 10px;
}

li > a.customClass::before{
 color: green;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing pseudo-elements with preprocessors. They are **very** different things.

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong. I wanted to say pseudo-elements (:before, :after, :first-line, ...)

Comment: :first-line is a pseudo-element. https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-css-pseudo-elements/

Comment: Here you are a list of pseudo-class https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: thanks, your answer solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome :)